# Drupal 6 failing to login user in IE7 but forwarding to user account page

Tags: 6, users

We have just updated a Drupal 6 website to Drupal 6.22 for a client. However, the client is now no longer able to login to their account when using IE7. After clicking "Log in" the client is correctly being forwarded to their user account page, but is getting a "You are not authorized to access this page" message and remain unauthenticated. The client has now choice but to use IE7 at work, so switching browser is not an option.

We have tried testing this in various browsers in our office (Chrome, Firefox, IE8 - we don't have access to IE7) and can successfully sign-in to the site every time.

We have tried repairing the sessions table (in case that was corrupted) and still no luck. Our cookie domain is being set in settings.php as: $cookie_domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following in order:

1. Ask the user to clear their browser cache.
2. Rebuild permissions - admin/content/node-settings/rebuild
3. Create a test account with the same roles.
4. Manually verify the roles and permissions haven't changed.

Comment: 3 and 4 have already been done. It doesn't strike me as a permissions issue as we have been able to successfully login using the client's credentials from our end. It could be the browser cache, we will ask the client to try that. Personally my suspicions are that it is something to do with cookies as we've discovered that the user table is showing them as having logged in even if they don't appear to be.

Comment: Clearing the cache and cookies fixed the problem.